# call to primitive JPA method throws WrongClassException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

```
 public static UserDetail UserDetail.findUserDetail(Long id) {
        if (id == null) return null;
        return entityManager().find(UserDetail.class, id);
    }
```

We are using spring Roo. Above is Roo generated finder method. Partial stack trace is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1501237 was not of the specified subclass: com.***.***.user.UserDetail (Discriminator: FacebookUserDetail)
```

Has anyone come across this exception?

**EDIT**
This question and following questions are related to same issue.

[Java class file truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916962/java-class-file-truncated)

I have two projects. My one project (say project2) depends on another project(project2). Both projects are maven project and project1 is listed in dependancies of project2. When I compile project2, all the class files from project1 should be copied to project2 (I imagine). But, I see that the file size of one of the class files in project1 is different than file size of class file for the same class in project2. If I decompile the files I get following results.

Decompiled FacebookUserDetail.class from project1:

```
package com.***.domain.user.external;

import com.***.domain.user.UserDetailType;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.CFlowCounter;
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect;
import org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl;

@Configurable
@Entity
public class FacebookUserDetail extends ExternalUserDetail
{
  public FacebookUserDetail()
  {
    JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this); if ((!AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) && (AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(localJoinPoint))) AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
  }

  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId(String facebookId)
  {
    String str = facebookId; JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, null, null, str); if ((AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.ajc$cflowCounter$1.isValid()) && (AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.hasAspect())) return (FacebookUserDetail)findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody1$advice(str, localJoinPoint, AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.aspectOf(), null, ajc$tjp_0, localJoinPoint); return findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody0(str, localJoinPoint);
  }

  public UserDetailType getExternalUserDetailType()
  {
    return UserDetailType.FACEBOOK;
  }

  static
  {
    ajc$preClinit(); } 
  public static long countFacebookUserDetails() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$countFacebookUserDetails(); } 
  public static List<FacebookUserDetail> findAllFacebookUserDetails() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findAllFacebookUserDetails(); } 
  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetail(Long paramLong) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetail(paramLong); } 
  public static List<FacebookUserDetail> findFacebookUserDetailEntries(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetailEntries(paramInt1, paramInt2); } 
  public static TypedQuery<FacebookUserDetail> findFacebookUserDetailsByUserIdEquals(String paramString) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Finder.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Finder$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetailsByUserIdEquals(paramString); } 
  public String toString() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_ToString$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$toString(this); }

}
```

Decompiled FacebookUserDetail.class from project2

```
package com.***.domain.user.external;

import com.***.domain.user.UserDetailType;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.CFlowCounter;
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect;
import org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl;

public class FacebookUserDetail extends ExternalUserDetail
{
  public FacebookUserDetail()
  {
    JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this); if ((!AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) && (AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(localJoinPoint))) AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
  }

  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId(String facebookId)
  {
    String str = facebookId; JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, null, null, str); if ((AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.ajc$cflowCounter$1.isValid()) && (AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.hasAspect())) return (FacebookUserDetail)findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody1$advice(str, localJoinPoint, AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.aspectOf(), null, ajc$tjp_0, localJoinPoint); return findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody0(str, localJoinPoint);
  }

  public UserDetailType getExternalUserDetailType()
  {
    return UserDetailType.FACEBOOK;
  }

  static
  {
    ajc$preClinit();
  }
}
```

My question is: What are possible reasons for truncated class file in project2?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810287/hibernate-inheritance-and-relationship-mapping-generics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334197/discriminator-wrongclassexception-jpa-with-hibernate-backend

Comment: Not helpful. My UserDetail class has multiple subclasses like FacebookUserDetail, TwitterUserDetail etc. All I am doing is UserDetail ud = UserDetail.findUserDetail(id); dype of that instance is FacebookUserDetail.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the error you have the following scenario:
you request an entity of type `UserDetail` with that ID (which should have the DTYPE/discriminator column value equal to `FacebookUserDetail` or other that extend `UserDetail`), but in your DB the DTYPE is another. You have to correct your DB for that.

Or it could also be, that `FacebookUserDetail` is not recognized as being a DTYPE of the same hierarchy. Try debugging a bit, e.g testing what is returned if you search for a `FacebookUserDetail` instance of the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your super class and subclasse didn't share the same id in the database for the requested record 1501237

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious you have an inheritance problem, take a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance